# Is there a way to to extract output context in google dialog flow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I would like to know if I could extract output context(one that is set using the dialogflow console) from the fulfillment request.

This is important for me to programmatically handle the query since same set of user utterance could trigger different event handlers depending upon the previous statement/conversation utterance of the user.

Comment: What language are you using? Assuming you are using NodeJS and [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/86a844a34ce61a665fa3687afe91af68b3dca0b8/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js), you can use getContext() method to get an output context.

Comment: Hi Anshuman,

I am using Python.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my question to extract the context that one sets using the dialogflow console in Python is

[image]